# Does broadleaf support Phonegap?

Tags: phonegap-build, broadleaf-commerce

We are almost decided on using Broadleaf as an e-commerce solution for our website. The only thing we are unsure about is the Phonegap support. Can we create a Phonegap app out of the e-commerce website created using Broadleaf?

Google search for the same suggests since Thymeleaf (used as the front end technology in Broadleaf) is a server side technology, it won't support Phonegap as such.

Can anyone suggest an approach how to tackle this ? Should we use JSPs with pure HTML & Ajax calls as the front end which can later be used in the Phonegap application instead of Thymeleaf ? Is it even possible ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jitesh

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a Phonegap application, I believe you would use REST APIs to interface with Broadleaf. In this scenario Broadleaf wouldn't have a frontend associated with it at all, it would just return XML or JSON. All of your HTML/JS/CSS would be using the Phonegap libraries and would be distributed with your mobile application.

By the way, Thymeleaf is analogous to JSPs in what it does or doesn't do. You can think of them as the same kind of technology. You can use either one to build a mobile web application and style it however you want, but I believe the real draw of Phonegap is to distribute native applications with a native look and feel for each platform. In that case all the HTML/JS/CSS that you write would live in the "native" application and not anywhere on the Broadleaf server.

So, Broadleaf is compatible with Phonegap in the same way that Broadleaf is compatible with other native mobile applications: via the REST APIs.

Comment: So what we need to do is to create a responsive web application using HTML/JS/CSS and call Broadleaf REST APIs. In that way we can use that as a web application and also can feed it to Phonegap to create a native app? Is the understanding correct ?